# Very simple RegEx: Find occurrence but not in one case

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

Hi Stackoverflowianers,

please help me solving a simple regex problem:

Given strings (e.g.):

```
Hollg 21, Bergg 15, Rosenweg 81, Fernblickg 30
```

I want to replace all occurrences of a "g" followed by an empty space and a digit with the word "gasse" BUT NOT: if the regex finds the `g` in `weg 81`.

What I already tried: `/[^(we)]g \d+/g`

This regex works well but it takes not only the `g` but also the letter before the `g` (results: `lg 21, gg 15, kg 30`). I only need the `g 21`, the `g 15` and the `g 81`...

I'm sure it is very simple but I cant get it to work.

Comment: Hi and welcome, the `g` modifier is in JavaScript and not in PHP.

Comment: Surely SOers would be a hell of a lot easier to write, yes?

Answer (score 3):

To make sure that `g` is not preceded by `we` (which forms `weg`), you should use *zero-width negative look-behind* `(?<!pattern)`:

```
/(?<!we)g(?= \d)/
```

Zero-width negative look-behind will check that it is not possible to find `we` right before the current position in the input string. Since it only checks without consuming text, it is *zero-width*.

I also modified the pattern to include a *zero-width positive look-ahead* `(?=pattern)` that checks for presence of space and digit **without consuming the text**, i.e. it will not make the text matching the pattern inside the `(?=pattern)` part of the match. This way, we don't have to capture the digit and put it back in the replacement string.

As a summary, the regex above will check that `we` is not preceding `g`, and `g` is followed by space and a digit. (Well, there is no need to check for *one or more* - since the presence of one digit would satisfy the *one or more* condition anyway).

Then you can write your replacement code as:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/(?<!we)g(?= \d)/', 'gasse', $inputString);
```

Comment: Nice... I didn't even thing about the look ahead to remove the need to put the token in the replacement string.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast first answere!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, a minor modification to your regex and this should work for you

Rather than using a normal exclusion operation `[^we]` you need to use a negative lookbehind to remove anything that matches the `we` rather than just a `g` following an `e`.  (See comments between me and nhahtdh)

```
<?php
$regex = '/(?<!we)g (\d+)/';

$input = 'Hollg 21, Bergg 15, Rosenweg 81, Fernblickg 30, weg 81';


$output = preg_replace($regex, 'gasse $1', $input);

//output = Holgasse 21, Bergasse 15, Rosenweg 81, Fernblicgasse 30, weg 81
```

You need to group the digit in your regex then use the reference to it in your replacement i.e the `$1`

Comment: `[^(we)]` This doesn't have the meaning that you want. It will match any character that is not `w`, `e`, `(` or `)`. It just happens to work for this test case. You will fail on `Abewg 44`

Comment: @nhahtdh good point, I actually missed those brackets in that part of the regex.  Removed from answer

Comment: The problem is still there actually. Please look at my test case again. Another test case is `ceg 33`

Comment: Got you.  Need to change it to a negative look behind, not a simple exclusion... unless you can find another test case that breaks this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression instead:

```
<?php
$expression = '/(?<!we)g\s(\d+)/';

$input = 'Hollg 21, Bergg 15, Rosenweg 81, Fernblickg 30, weg 81, ceg 45';

$output = preg_replace($expression, 'gasse $1', $input);

//output = Holgasse 21, Bergasse 15, Rosenweg 81, Fernblicgasse 30, weg 81, cegasse 45

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to for your answere, I'll try out all solutions and will give you a reply if and how it worked! Thnx. again!

Comment: Worked like a charm...! Thanx to all of you.